# Kentico Page Wizard issues

Tags: kentico

I am using the Kentico Page Wizard Manager to guide users through a particular page flow. All of my pages use the Portal Engine, and are configured to use the page nesting setting `Use page template settings (All ancestor pages)`.  The ancestor pages do have `Page Placeholder` web parts in them, and are working correctly.

I have my page hierarchy set up like this:

```
A
   B
   C
   D
   E
F
```

Where B:E are underneath A, and F is the next sibling of A.

I have my Page Wizard Manager configured as the sole content web part on page A, and I have it `Restrict step order` set to `Checked` and `Final step URL` set to page `F`.  In the `Navigation` tab of A, I have it set to `Redirect to first child`.

I am having two issues:

1. On pages B:E, I have Page Wizard Button parts to move users from one page to the next.  However, when visiting the pages, the buttons *never* show up to users.
2. Page B is a login/register page. I am using a `Logon mini form` web part, and a `Registration Form` web part on this page.  I also added a `Page wizard step action` to skip this page if the current user is already authenticated.  This skip functionality doesn't ever seem to trigger, however the Logon mini form does correctly disappear when the user is logged in.  My step action settings are: `Enabled=Checked`, `Action Type=Skip`, `Validate Step=Checked`, `Action Condition={% CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated #%}`.

I've been referencing [the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/displaying-data-advanced-scenarios/creating-wizards-on-websites), and as far as I can tell, I am using all of these components correctly.

Any ideas on what could be causing these issues? It seems like *none* of the Page Wizard functionality is working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a Page Template issue. All of my pages were using an ad-hoc instance of a common page template. This common page template was set to use a shared layout.

When I created a new Page Template specifically for this page that does *not* use a shared layout, all the Page Wizard functionality started working.

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons are on page A, they need to be moved to each step page i.e.: B, C, D, E, etc.

On your Page Wizard Step Action, uncheck the validation step box and set your condition to:

`{% MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.IsAuthenticated %}`

Also, make sure your Page Wizard Step Action web part is the last one on the page. 
 This should resolve your issues.

Comment: Thanks, Brenden!  The buttons are on the individual step pages.  I've updated my step actions to be as you described.  Still no luck.  I am running on Kentico 11, if that makes any difference.